# Python2.5 to Python2.7 Performance degradation

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have a software that builds and we monitor build times every day

Recently, we have updated our software to use python2.7 from python2.5 and the build times have increased (things got slower).

Without digging in, is this expected outcome?

Python2.7 is generally slower than Python2.5?

Answer (score 1):

I recently migrated a project from 2.5 to 2.7 and experienced the same.

For me it was that my program was not thread safe. [This](http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe) was an interesting and enlightening read.